# photo.media.m display large flickr images

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I'm trying to display Flickr images in a masonry grid. I have it working however the images are too pixelated, so I need to show the large version of the image.

I know to do this I need to change (change the m before .jpg to b)

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5830/23743383991_5c7fecec1a_m.jpg

to

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5830/23743383991_5c7fecec1a_b.jpg

How can I add b to the following line of code?

```
photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '">'
```

Full code below

```
//AJAX
    var flickrAPI = "//api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&extras=url_l";

    var photoSelection = 'ALL';

    var flickrOptions = {
        id: "49752549@N04",
        tags: photoSelection,
        format: "json"
    };

    function displayPhotos(data){

        var photoHTML = '<div class="grid-sizer"></div>';


        $.each( data.items, function(i, photo){
            photoHTML += '<div class="grid-item">';
            photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '">'
            photoHTML += '</div>';
        });

        photoHTML += '';

        $('.grid').html(photoHTML);
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$.each( data.items, function(i, photo){
        photoHTML += '<div class="grid-item">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '">'
        photoHTML += '</div>';
    });
```

to

```
$.each( data.items, function(i, photo){
        var x = photo.media.m;
        var firstPart = (x).substr(0,x.lastIndexOf("_m"));
        var secondPart = (x).substr(x.lastIndexOf("_m")+2);            
        photoHTML += '<div class="grid-item">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="' + (firstPart + "_b" + secondPart ) + '">'
        photoHTML += '</div>';
    });
```

Don't suggest this method though, there must be options in the flickr API to make changes for image sizes.